# Why UIView animation fails when text within the UIView is changed before the animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

Im relatively new to `UIView` animations and made a simple up/down animation of a "infoView"s frame.

[image]

The dark blue area is touchable and toggle the animation which works fine so far.

The problem is only the change of the TEXT from the `UILabel` on the top right. If I change content of the Label before, after or in the completion block of the animation the animation always fails. -> then it doesn't animate up anymore... it seems to blink one time. I don't know what's the problem here....

some code:
i save the two frame positions for the animation:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        infoViewRectNotVisible = infoView.frame
        infoViewRectVisible = CGRect(x: infoView.frame.minX, y: searchBar.frame.minY, width: infoView.frame.width, height: infoView.frame.height)
 }
```

and i simply animate the infoView up and down:

```
@IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        infoIsVisible = !infoIsVisible

        showHideLabel.text = infoIsVisible ? "hide Info" : "show Info"

        print(infoView.frame)
        print(infoViewRectVisible)
        print(infoViewRectNotVisible)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.infoView.frame = self.infoIsVisible ? self.infoViewRectVisible : self.infoViewRectNotVisible
        })
}
```

**If i comment** showHideLabel.text = infoIsVisible ? "hide Info" : "show Info" **out, the animation works as accepted otherwise it dont animate up anymore**

The infoIsVisible Bool and the saved frames (infoViewRectVisible & infoViewRectNotVisible) are always correct.

I have tried:

- `.setNeedsLayout()`, `.layoutIfNeeded()`
- set text in the completion block of the animation
- `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false
- ....

I really dont know why i cant change the text - or do I completely misunderstand something?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you use Autolayout/SnapKit to position the label inside of the blue view?

Comment: Hey, yeah the label is positioned top, right with Autolayout.

Comment: So when you change the text the label changes its frame to `intrinsicContentSize` to fit the new content. After that it probably implicitly calls `setNeedsLayout`, so I guess Autolayout basically interferes with your manual UIView animation. Could you try setting fixed size constraints for the label and try again?

Comment: Hey thx for the reply! I tried to set the size but its still the same animation bug. Maybe it has to be something with the Autolayout because the infoView is at first in the unvisible/bottom position - with Autolayout. But i didn't figured out the problem yet..

Comment: I suppose the label still calls relayout even without changing the frame size. I suggest that you either only use autolayout or manual frame setup in both cases.

Comment: Instead of manually changing the frame of `infoView`, try setting up its top constraint, change its `constant` property based on `infoIsVisible` and then call `infoView.setNeedsLayout()` inside the `UIView.animate...` block.

Comment: The problem is you are mixing constraints with setting frame properties. You should only do one or the other. Animate with constraints instead.

Comment: Hey @ctomato yeah with animated constraints everything works fine, thx! I didn't know that I cant/should not animate frames in "autolayouted" Views or that there can happen crazy and for me unlogic things^^ I also thought that .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false prevents that case, but maybe i used it wrong.... I think its better/cleaner to animate the contraints!
Thx again! And write an answer that i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to animate frames to achieve the desired result. You could just animate proper view transforms instead:

```
let yTranslation = CGAffineTransform(
    translationX: 0.0,
    y: infoView.frame.height - searchBar.frame.height
)

UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.3,
    delay: 0,
    options: .curveEaseInOut,
    animations: {
        self.infoView.transform = self.infoIsVisible ? yTranslation : .identity
    }
)
```